# Publishing ASP.NET vNext / DNX combined with CLR class library

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've added my 'traditional' DAL project to an ASP.NET vNext and worked/debugged with it locally without any problems. But when I tried to publish it to Azure it would not. It states '3>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.', but there are 0 in the Error List, also the project runs just fine.

So is it possible to combine 'old' 4.5.1 projects with DNX targetted projects? If so, is Publishing now just an issue at the moment or something else?

As a workaround I tried to create a DNX class library, but that wouldn't allow me (in VS 2015) to add References using the Browse button, so I couldn't port my old class library to the new format as I also require 2 DLL's.

The log of the build

```
3>------ Publish started: Project: Example.Kitchen, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Project "Example.Kitchen.xproj" (MSDeployPublish target(s)):
    Building with tools version "14.0".
    Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
    Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
    Configuration=Debug
    Platform=AnyCPU
    Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('..\artifacts\bin\Example.Kitchen\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('..\artifacts\bin\Example.Kitchen\')).
    Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('..\artifacts\obj\Example.Kitchen\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('..\artifacts\obj\Example.Kitchen\')).
    Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('..\artifacts\obj\Example.Kitchen\Debug\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('..\artifacts\obj\Example.Kitchen\Debug\')).
    Using "GetRuntimeToolingPath" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Tasks.dll".
    Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (!Exists('$(RuntimeToolingExe)')) was evaluated as (!Exists('C:\Users\Gabriel\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin\dnx.exe')).
    Using "DefaultExternalToolsPath" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Tasks.dll".
    Using "GetRuntimeVersion" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Tasks.dll".
    rmdir /S /Q "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\"
    Using "Dnu" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\..\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Tasks.dll".
    Environment variables:
    Path=D:\Development\dotnet\Example\Example.Kitchen\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\extensions\microsoft\web tools\external;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\NativeBinaries\x86;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Users\Gabriel\.dnx\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\npm";C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\extensions\microsoft\web tools\external\.git
    C:\Users\Gabriel\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin\dnu.cmd publish "D:\Development\dotnet\Example\Example.Kitchen" --out "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp" --configuration Debug --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6 --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --quiet
    Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta6-12256
    Copying to output path C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp
    Time elapsed 00:00:03.4408766
Done building project "Example.Kitchen.xproj" -- FAILED.

3>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What errors are in the error list (visual studio window) if any?

Comment: @Gabriël I'm having the same problem. Just added a testing repo https://github.com/petrsvihlik/aspnet5_deploytest to the https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2467 (guess it's your issue :))

Comment: This is the answer for now I guess...

Comment: They have closed the bug https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/pull/2745 :D it works with the latest bits?

Answer (score 0):

#### Fixing what I already have

If you don't want to upgrade, you could try running the following command from your project directory:

```sh
C:\Users\Gabriel\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin\dnu.cmd publish "D:\Development\dotnet\Example\Example.Kitchen" --out "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp" --configuration Debug --runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6 --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --quiet
```

However, remove the `--quiet` flag and make sure to run `dnvm list` to ensure you have the `dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6` runtime.

#### Recommended step:

I think this has been solved in the latest `beta8`.

Make sure to [update to the latest version (RC1)](http://get.asp.net/) (including tooling) and ensure that you are not using older packages (no beta6/beta8).

Also, make sure to looking at the [breaking changes](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones/1.0.0-rc1) that has been introduced in the RC1.